# load credentials based on choice parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Team,
I want to set credentials based on the choice selected. any hint how can achieve this?

```
    parameters {
        choice( choices: ['ChooseOne', 'team1', 'team2',], name: 'JenkinsInstance')
    }
```

```
            steps {
                container('main') {
                        withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins-team1-api-token' , passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME']]) {
                        sh '''
                        echo "Creating UsernamePassword credentials ID..."
                        src/jenkins/jenkins-build-agent/create-creds.sh
                        '''.stripIndent()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

what i want is if team2 is chosen then other creds are loaded.

```
            steps {
                container('main') {
                      if choice.param == team1
                        withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins-team1-api-token' , passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME']]) 
                      if choice.param == team2
                         withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins-team2-api-token' , passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME']])
{
                        sh '''
                        echo "Creating UsernamePassword credentials ID..."
                        src/jenkins/jenkins-build-agent/create-creds.sh
                        '''.stripIndent()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, what is the result of your build then?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that much simpler:

```java
parameters {
    choice name: 'JenkinsInstance',
        choices: ['ChooseOne', 'team1', 'team2']
    }

// ...
    steps {
        container('main') {
            withCredentials(
                [[
                    $class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding',
                    credentialsId: "jenkins-${params.JenkinsInstance}-api-token",
                    passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN',
                    usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME'
                ]]
            ) {
                sh script: 'src/jenkins/jenkins-build-agent/create-creds.sh',
                    label: 'Creating UsernamePassword credentials ID...'
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the double quotes around the `credentialsId` value.

In case of default username/password credentials type (not Hashicorp Vault ones), this becomes even more simple if you can modify your shell script to use `<credential_variable_name>_USR` and `<credential_variablw_name>_PSW` variables:

```java
environment {
    JENKINS_CREDENDIALS = credentials("jenkins-${params.JenkinsInstance}-api-token")
}

// ...
    steps {
        container('main') {
            {
                sh script: 'src/jenkins/jenkins-build-agent/create-creds.sh',
                    label: 'Creating UsernamePassword credentials ID...'
            }
        }
    }
```

Also note usage of the `label` parameter of `sh` step instead of invocation of `echo` within the script which is more clean.